# Store large number of file pointers in php array

Tags: php, arrays, file

So I have a specific script that needs to be optimized. The fact is, I'm going to read a 160gB file, and for each line I have to store the first two letters of md5 hash and the plain word.

I did put some timers in a test code to check for bottlenecks, and a big one of course is file writing.

I have 16^4 files to handle. For now I'm writing everything in buffers and only printing it to files when the buffer is of a certain size (according to my ram).

The problem is, I still have to fopen, fwrite and fclose, each time for each file. This takes long. I ran some benchmarks, and using fopen before the for loop and fclose after the loop does speed up things by a 20x factor (obviously).

So I was thinking, why wouldn't I make an array, just like the one I have to store my 65536 buffers, to store the file pointers ?

I tried, but I have an error. Here's my code :

```
for($i = 0;$i < 16;$i++)
{
for($j = 0;$j < 16;$j++)
{
for($k = 0;$k < 16;$k++)
{
for($l = 0;$l < 16;$l++)
{
     $ijkl = $hexa[$i].$hexa[$j].$hexa[$k].$hexa[$l];
     $fichiers[] = $ijkl;
     $fichiers[$ijkl] = [];
     $fichiers[$ijkl][0] = fopen(realpath("my/path/to/" . $hexa[$i] . "/" . $hexa[$j] . 
     $hexa[$k] . $hexa[$l]),"a");
}
}
}
}
```

So, when I run this, I have two different errors. First one is "failed to open stream: File exists", which seems hard to understand because it does create each file even if it prints this error.

Second one is "failed to open stream; invalid argument". Which according to several posts I saw on stackoverflow would be the path. That's why I tried realpath here. I also tried "my\path\to\" and 'my\path\to', didn't work. Which is odd because it used to work when all the fopens where made during for loop.

Is there anything that prevents us to create an array of file pointers ?

Thank you for answering :)

EDIT : Actually here's my whole code :

```
<?php
set_time_limit(3600000);
ini_set('memory_limit', '4096M');
$time_pre = microtime(true);
$chunkSize = (1<<29);
$bufferSize = (1<<15);
$position = 0;
$filesize = filesize("my\\path\\to\\file");
$dico = fopen("my\\path\\to\\file","r+");
$hexa = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f");
for($i = 0;$i < 16;$i++)
{
    for($j = 0;$j < 16;$j++)
    {
        for($k = 0;$k < 16;$k++)
        {
            for($l = 0;$l < 16;$l++)
            {
                $ijkl = "$hexa[$i]$hexa[$j]$hexa[$k]$hexa[$l]";
                $$ijkl = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
while(!feof($dico))
{
    fseek($dico, $position);
    $chunk = fread($dico, $chunkSize);
    $last_lf_pos = strrpos($chunk, "\n");
    $buffer = mb_substr($chunk,0,$last_lf_pos);
    $tab = explode("\n",$buffer);
    $limiteBuffer = count($tab);

    for($i = 0;$i < $limiteBuffer;$i++)
    {
        $md5 =  md5($tab[$i]);
        $add4 = "$md5[0]$md5[1]$md5[2]$md5[3]";
        $$add4 .= "$md5[4]$md5[5]$tab[$i]\n";
        if(isset($$add4{$bufferSize}))
        {
            $baseFichier = "my\\path\\to\\$md5[0]\\$md5[1]$md5[2]$md5[3]";
            $fichier = fopen($baseFichier,"a");
            fwrite($fichier, $$add4);
            fclose($fichier);
            $$add4 = "";
        }
    }
    for($i = 0;$i < 16;$i++)
    {
        for($j = 0;$j < 16;$j++)
        {
            for($k = 0;$k < 16;$k++)
            {
                for($l = 0;$l < 16;$l++)
                {
                    $ijkl = "$hexa[$i]$hexa[$j]$hexa[$k]$hexa[$l]";
                    if($$ijkl != "")
                    {
                        $baseFichier = "my\\path\\to\\$hexa[$i]\\$hexa[$j]$hexa[$k]$hexa[$l]";
                        $fichier = fopen($baseFichier,"a");
                        fwrite($fichier, $$ijkl);
                        fclose($fichier);
                        $$ijkl = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $position += $last_lf_pos;
    if(($position+$chunkSize) > $filesize) $chunkSize = $filesize-$position;
        $buffer = NULL;

}
fclose($dico);
$time_post = microtime(true);
$exec_time = $time_post - $time_pre;
echo "Total : " .$exec_time;
?>
```

If you have any idea of speed optimization.

Comment: I'd seriously consider using a database (sqlite for instance) rather than a bunch of files.

Comment: Firstly - do you get these errors for every file or only after a point.  Secondly - there is a limit to the number of files you can have open at any point and you are probably close to or exceeding it - this seems like a bad idea in general.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I did tried databases, but my system actually works better. I just create those files then I just have to look for specific lines. A database would be fast but would also take much more disk space (we're talking about more than 100 billion lines total). The error does appear after 4095 files were created. I guess this is a maximum. Thank you for your answers. Don't worry this is not production code, it's local that's why I'm trying crazy things.

Comment: I have done things like this in the past, as first tip you are doing 16 directories with 4096 files, try better 256 directories with 256 files (it is faster). Asking about the problem, is not possible to make it in a single file calculating the absolute position using the pointers?. What are you storing in those files?.

Comment: If i get it, Input is a single file of 160gb, and output is for each line a "hash" and the plain text of those lines, stored in one of those 65536 files (based in the hash previuosly calculated)?

Comment: The input file is used to make rainbow tables. I actually never tried with 256 directories. I'll do it right away. I did try 16 /16/65536 which was slow as hell because it needed to handle more than one million files. I could also try with pointers but I'm not sure it would be faster. Actually I'm able to find 500 entries in 20 to 30s, because I'm using little files and I know exactly in which file I'll find the answer.

Comment: 16/16/65536 is slow because it searchs the file in a list of 65536 files and its need to check all the previous file entries in the dir until it finds the good one, try 256/256/256 it will run a lot faster.

Comment: The faster way would be probably 16/16/16/16/16/16, this would find the file with less sectors than all the others methods. Here is where you read less number of disk sectors and aditionally it will be a constant time (in 16/16/65536 sometimes the file can be at the end of all and the average search will be 32768 files to find the right one).

Comment: I just tried 256/256 but it was exactly as fast as 16/4096 :( Looks like the bottleneck isn't in reading or writing the files, as it is on a brand new SSD. I'm still trying to find a way to improve speed, the process will take a few days. I have to read the 160gB file at least 4 times for different kind of hashes. As of now, the two process that takes time are md5() function, and the writing with fopen, fwrite and fclose. I'm using a 32kB buffer to write, maybe I could try more but I want to duplicate this script in 4 different threads so I have to be careful to memory usage.

Comment: I posted the whole script if you see anything I could improve to speed things up.

Comment: This looks like the wrong solution, a database (any database) is going to be more robust. The errors you mention are probably because the folders don't exist, and there are attempt to write to the same file several times (the first time of which it doesn't exist). If you want to continue with this solution: do less work (`< 2`) so you can iterate faster and step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: I first tried using a database, but I would need a bunch of teraBytes to store everything I want. I also want something that can access hundreds of entries in less time as possible, and all the DB I tried weren't able to do that. Here I'm building specific files to match my goal. The folders did exist, I created them just before and gave them the right permissions. Actually all the files were successfully created, even if the script shown errors. For now i'm making a monothread script, but then I'll split the big file and will run on multiple threads (I have a 3600X Ryzen).

Comment: One tip, if you are using ssd it is not and adventage to read those enormous chunks of data (256mb) to search after the last \n. And explode must be very slow there, it is faster to read line by line directly from the file,

Comment: probably strrpos is done ok internally looking from last to first character, but  mb_substr creates a full copy of everything (copy 256mb even from memory to memory is not a good idea).

Comment: read line by line instead of split + mbsubstr and it will be faster and small memory usage. Thinking in multithread you will need that.

Comment: and as i told you try 16 entries in each directory  (16/16/16/16/16/16, even if it is ssd it will be faster, you will find a file in around 8+8+8+8+8+8 instead of 8+8+32768 of average case with your case)

Comment: I spend a lot of times in things like this, i have had some millions of files in some of my tests too. Actually in doing a new one that will need 8TB of hd and a AMD 3950x working some days in multithread (32 probably). Sometimes I use ZIPs to minimize the number of files in the file system, but zip files are not concurrent.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Actually at first I used fgets to get each line one by one. But then I figured it was faster to use chunks of data. It may be an issue with the size of my benchmark file, which is 25mB so of course it does fill in the memory pretty easily. With this file it's 12s to complete with chunks versus 18s with fgets. I'll try with a bigger file when I have some time.